# Can't create lib files with CMake

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use OpenCV with eclipse so to do that I followed these steps:
I downloaded:

1. OpenCV 3.2.0
2. mingw-w64-install
3. Cmake 3.1.1
4. eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
   then I applied each step in this tutorial 
   http://jeanvitor.com/installing-cpp-opencv-3-2/
   the problem appears when I tried to build the Mingw_build file, I got this error : [image]

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type make: *** [Makefile:160: all] Error 2
>
>       make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfzdV.png): *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:583:3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/all] Error 2
>       make[2]: *** [3rdparty\openexr\CMakeFiles\IlmImf.dir\build.make:363: 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/Imath/ImathMatrixAlgo.cpp.obj] Error 1
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(double&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)' 
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)' 
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)' 
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)' 
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)' 
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)'
>       no matching function for call to 'max(float&, int)' 
>       no matching function for call to 'max(T&, int)' ImathMatrixAlgo.cpp /OpenCV-Release@mybuild/[Source directory]/3rdparty/openexr/Imath   line 1095   C/C++ Problem

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What is the actual problem here? Why do you want to set the library path and why cannot you build library if you cannot set the library path? The default library output path should be working well and should be enough for your need. Also, how the screenshot is related at all to your question??

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your cmake files and your  C++ code?

Comment: ok I'll add more details

Comment: I can't even see the whole error on the screenshot. Drop the screenshot and paste the error as code here.

Comment: Also, even if there is no `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH`, you can install the libraries at the desired place yourself.

Comment: How can I do that by myself ??

Comment: well... I don't think there is any mechanism that blocks you from moving files around... have you tried? Installation is merely copying file in a specific place. Copy pasting the files at the desired place should do the trick

Comment: I tried to find the libraries opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_ml opencv_video opencv_features2d opencv_calib3d opencv_objdetect opencv_contrib opencv_legacy opencv_flann but I couldn't; all I have is opencv_world320d.lib without these it won't work

Comment: Why do you want to get a maximum between a (reference to) floating point and an int? Are you sure there *should* be such a function?

Comment: I just want to work with opencv and I'm trying to do that with eclipse I don't know what to do I just want to read an image as a first step